# ListCell doesn't show custom items

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm trying to create custom `ListCell<Chat>` but when I fill in by data the ListView on the main view is empty. I'm trying a combination of Spring Boot and JavaFX as described here: https://github.com/turais/TuraisJavaFxExamples. When I use `ListView<String>` it will show a list of strings as expected, but not my custom `ListCell<Chat>` when I try the custom implementation.

Where is the issue or I missed something cannot find second day...

Main Controller:

```
    public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtSearch;

    @FXML
    private ListView<Chat> lvChats;

    private ObservableList<Chat> chatsObservableList;

    @Autowired
    private ListChatCell listChatCell;


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.chatsObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(getTestList());

        lvChats.setItems(chatsObservableList);
        lvChats.setCellFactory(studentListView -> listChatCell);
    }

    @FXML
    public void showSettings() {

    }

    private List<Chat> getTestList() {
        List<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<>();



        chatList.add(new Chat("Last message 1", "Chat 1", "12:09", "3"));
        chatList.add(new Chat("Last message 2", "Chat 2", "14:09", "1"));

        return chatList;
    }
}
```

ListCell:

```
    public class ListChatCell extends ListCell<Chat> {

    @FXML
    private Text txtLastMessage;

    @FXML
    private Text txtChatName;

    @FXML
    private Text txtLastMessageTime;

    @FXML
    private Text txtUnreadMessage;

    @FXML
    private Pane pane;


    @FXML
    private ImageView imgChatIcon;


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Chat chat, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(chat, empty);

        if (empty || chat == null) {

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);

        } else {

            txtLastMessage.setText(chat.getLastMessage());
            txtChatName.setText(chat.getChatName());
            txtLastMessageTime.setText(String.valueOf(chat.getLastMessageTime()));
            txtUnreadMessage.setText(String.valueOf(chat.getNumberUnreadMessages()));

            imgChatIcon.setImage(new Image("tl.jpeg"));
            setText("help");
            setGraphic(pane);
        }

    }
}
```

My ListCell FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<Pane fx:id="pane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.client.manager.fx.ui.cell.ListChatCell">
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="imgChatIcon" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <GridPane minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="400.0">
               <children>
                  <Text fx:id="txtLastMessage" layoutX="90.0" layoutY="-1.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="LastMessageText" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Text fx:id="txtChatName" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ChatName" wrappingWidth="208.2060546875">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
                  <Text fx:id="txtLastMessageTime" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="TimeLastMessage" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                  <Text fx:id="txtUnreadMessage" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="NumberOfUnreadMessages" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
               </children>
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="321.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="305.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="128.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="71.0" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="189.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="95.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="295.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="105.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Main FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.client.manager.fx.ui.TelegramController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <items>
            <VBox prefHeight="323.0" prefWidth="198.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showSettings" text="Settings" />
                        <TextField fx:id="txtSearch" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <ListView fx:id="lvChats" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: `private ListChatCell listChatCell; ... lvChats.setCellFactory(studentListView -> listChatCell);` No, that's not how cell factories are supposed to work. You need to return different instances of the cell every time the factory is invoked. (It really surprises me returning the same cell instance over and over again does not yield an error.) Also the cell implementations are details of the GUI. Injecting the factory wouldn't be a good idea either.

Comment: Thanks @fabian, after changes It works as expected :-)